# An unusual proof of the image measure theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is Theorem 4.10, p. 101, of *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*, by Klenke. I have written an unusual proof which I think/hope is correct, and I'm wondering if anyone has any comments on it.

**Theorem**

> Let $(\varOmega, \mathcal A)$ and $(\varOmega', \mathcal A')$ be
> measurable spaces, let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\varOmega, \mathcal A)$
> and let $X \colon \varOmega \to \varOmega'$ be measurable. Let $\mu' = \mu \circ X^{-1}$ be the image measure of $\mu$ under the map $X$.
> Assume that $f: \varOmega' \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ is
> $\mu'$-integrable. Then $f \circ X \in \mathcal L^1(\mu)$ and
> \begin{equation} \int (f \circ X) d\mu = \int f d(\mu \circ X^{-1})
>  \end{equation}

**My Proof**

Let $\mathbb{E}'$ be the vector space of simple functions on $(\varOmega', \mathcal A')$, and $\mathbb{E}'^+$ be its cone of non-negative simple functions. Define $I' \colon \mathbb{E}'^+ \to [0, \infty]$ by $g' = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mathbf{1}_{A_i} \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mu'(A_i)$. Then, using the assumption that $f \colon \varOmega' \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mu'$-integrable, and the definition of the integral, we have
\begin{align}
    \int f \, d\mu' &= \int f^+ \, d\mu' - \int f^- \, d\mu'\\
    &= \sup \left\{ I'(g') \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\} - \sup \left\{ I'(h') \colon h' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, h' \leq f^- \right\}
\end{align}
By definition of $\mu'$, if $g' = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$ and $h' = \sum_{j = 1}^n \beta_j \, \mathbf{1}_{B_j}$, then
\begin{equation}
    I'(g') = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mu'(A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mu\left(X^{-1}(A_i)\right), \qquad I'(h') = \sum_{j = 1}^n \beta_j \, \mu'(B_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \beta_j \, \mu\left(X^{-1}(B_j)\right)
\end{equation}
If we define $\mathbb{E}$, $\mathbb{E}^+$ and $I$ similarly on $(\varOmega, \mathcal A)$, and define $F \colon \mathbb{E}'^+ \to \mathbb{E}^+$ by $\sum_{i = 1}^o \gamma_i \, \mathbf{1}_{C_i} \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^o \gamma_i \, \mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(C_i)}$, then we see that every $g'$ and $h'$ correspond respectively to a $F(g') =: g = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A_i)}$ and $F(h') =: h = \sum_{j = 1}^n \beta_j \, \mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(B_j)}$, which are elements of $\mathbb{E}^+$. Moreover, the line above shows that $I'(g') = I(g)$ and $I'(h') = I(h)$.

The inequality $g' \leq f^+$ on $\varOmega'$ implies that $g \leq f^+ \circ X$ on $\varOmega$. Indeed, assume that $g' \leq f^+$, and consider $\omega \in \varOmega$. If $\omega \in X^{-1}(A_i)$ for some $1 \leq i \leq m$, then $X(\omega) \in A_i$ and
\begin{equation}
    g(\omega) = \alpha_i = g'\left(X(\omega)\right) \leq f^+\left(X(\omega)\right) = f^+ \circ X(\omega)
\end{equation}
whence $g \leq f^+ \circ X$. If $\omega \notin X^{-1}(A_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots, m$, then we have
\begin{equation}
    g(\omega) = 0 = g'\left(X(\omega)\right) \leq f^+\left(X(\omega)\right) = f^+ \circ X(\omega)
\end{equation}
so the inequality $g \leq f^+ \circ X$ still holds. Similarly, $h' \leq f^-$ on $\varOmega'$ implies that $h \leq f^- \circ X$ on $\varOmega$.

It is clear that
\begin{equation}
\left\{ I\left(F(g')\right) \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\} \subset \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f^+ \circ X\right\}
\end{equation}
therefore
\begin{equation}
\sup \left\{ I\left(F(g')\right) \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\} \leq \sup \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f^+ \circ X\right\}
\end{equation}
Since $f^+$ is a non-negative, measurable function, there is a sequence $(f_n^+)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{E}'^+$ such that $f_n^+ \uparrow f^+$. This implies the existence of a sequence $\left(F(f_n^+)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{E}^+$ such that $F(f_n^+) \uparrow f^+ \circ X$. Since the limit of the integrals of such sequences of simple functions are (respectively) the integrals of their limits, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\sup \left\{ I\left(F(g')\right) \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\} = \sup \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f^+ \circ X\right\}
\end{equation}
and $\sup \left\{ I'(g') \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\} = \sup \left\{ I\left(F(g')\right) \colon g' \in \mathbb{E}'^+, g' \leq f^+ \right\}$, because the underlying sets contain exactly the same numbers. Using this information, and the fact that $f^+ \circ X = (f \circ X)^+$, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
    \int f^+ \, d\mu' = \int f^+ \circ X \, d\mu = \int (f \circ X)^+ \, d\mu
\end{equation}
The same reasoning for $f^-$ and $h'$ shows that
\begin{equation}
    \int f^- \, d\mu' = \int f^- \circ X \, d\mu = \int (f \circ X)^- \, d\mu
\end{equation}
Putting everything together, we have that
\begin{align*}
    \int f \, d\mu' &= \int f^+ \, d\mu' - \int f^- \, d\mu'\\
    &= \int (f \circ X)^+ \, d\mu - \int (f \circ X)^- \, d\mu
\end{align*}
Since $f \circ X \colon \varOmega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable and $(f \circ X)^+, (f \circ X)^- \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, we see that $f \circ X = (f \circ X)^+ - (f \circ X)^- \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, whence
\begin{equation}
    \int (f \circ X) \, d\mu = \int (f \circ X)^+ \, d\mu - \int (f \circ X)^- \, d\mu = \int f \, d\mu'
\end{equation}

Comment: TL;DR. What makes your proof unusual. Can you summarize this in a nutshell?

Comment: Every proof I've seen (admittedly not a lot) proceeds from indicator functions to simple functions to non-negative measurable functions and so on. My purported proof doesn't seem to work like that - it seems to work more directly with the definition of the integral of a non-negative measurable function. Sorry, that's the clearest explanation I've got. The proof was left as an exercise in the book and I wasn't familiar with the usual proof.

Comment: As far as I see you use heavily the cone $\mathbb E^{'+}$ of nonnegative simple functions. Also: the proof in H. Bauer, *Measure and Integraton Theory* that I just checked is a lot shorter.

Comment: @KurtG. I'll check that proof out. To be clear, I'm not claiming this is a particularly simple (purported) proof. Anyway, thanks for your time.